# Install confluent-kafka avro with pip

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

I'm trying to install the avro package for confluent-kafka with python3 on macOs Sierra.

Installing the confluent-kafka package works fine, no issues. The problem is when I try to install the avro package:

```
pip install confluent-kafka[avro]
```

I just get an error message from the bash, saying:

```
no matches found: confluent-kafka[avro]
```

How can I install this package? Anyone else that have managed to do it on mac?

Comment: Can you confirm that confluent-kafka is installed?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to install confluent-kafka, and if I try to import confluent-kafka that works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing directly from github

```
pip install git+git://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python.git
```

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you are not using bash (in my case it was zsh), the `[]` might mess with your shell. The following should solve this:

```
pip install "confluent-kafka[avro]"
```

For me this worked with the default install from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/confluent-kafka/), no need for the github URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!** In my case it was python version

1. I was using **python 3.10.1** version
2. Uninstall **python 3.10.1** and **python Launcher** from *add or remove programs*
3. Download python 3.7.0 for x64 bit using this [link](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0-amd64.exe) or download from here [Link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/)
4. Now you can: `pip install confluent-kafka[avro]`